# What is the correct way to use the bash if else && || shortcut?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have come across some strange behavious (well probably not strange but I don't understand it !)

I want to write some if / e,se statements using the bash shorthand syntax:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

The output of the above code gives:

```
true
```

Now the code above actually works fine. But this next code does not:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && infMsg "true" || infMsg "false"
```

*infMsg* is just a function. The output from the above code gives:

```
true
false
```

I only want it to say 'true'.

Is there something I am missing in the way the && || syntax handles exit codes from functions ?

Comment: does that function happen to return a non-zero value?

Answer (score 18):

I suspect your exit code for 'infMsg' is not 0 (success).
If we break down the first piece of code:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

What's happening is:

- The `[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && echo "true"` portion of code is evaluated first since `&&` has a higher precedence than `||` (more info[here[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html))
- The first half of that returns true. Then, **since the first half was true**, the second half executes the `echo "true"` statement. (&& -> If part one is true, run the second part)
- Now we have the `|| echo "false"`. This part actually doesn't get executed since the first half (`echo "true"`) returned true since the echo printed successfully (**(||-> If part one is false, run the second part).**).

Now if we break down the second piece of code:

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && infMsg "true" || infMsg "false"
```

What's ***most likely happening*** is:

- `[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && infMsg "true"` is evaluated. The first side is true. Then, **since the first half was true**, the second half executes the `infMsg "true"`  statement. (&& -> If part one is true, run the second part).
- Now we have `|| infMsg "false"`. If the `infMsg "true"`  from the previous command didn't return a status code that is interpreted as success (0), the first half is interpreted as false, triggering the `infMsg "false"`(**(||-> If part one is false, run the second part).**)..

The important info to pull away here:

- || only runs the second half if the first half is FALSE.
- && only run the second half if the first half is TRUE.

Comment: ok cool - thanks. I will check the ingMsg function and make sure it is explicitly returning an error code.

Comment: I did some testing and wrote a new infMsg function with **no** return code and it still worked as I expected. I thought that if a function exited with no explicit return it returns 0 if there were no internal errors.
So I am still confused:

`infMsg (){
    echo -e "**$1"
}`

`[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && infMsg "Test success" || infMsg "Test FAIL"`

Still gives me: `**Test success`

Comment: Without an explicit `return` command, the exit status of a function is the exit status of the last command executed in the function. In this case, it's the exit status of `echo -e "**$1"`, which is (always?) 0.

Comment: A warning not to use this construct: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015